# Regex for removing (non-Javadoc) @see comments?

Tags: regex, eclipse, javadoc

Is there any chance to remove all comments with the following structure in the whole source-code:

```
/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see this.is.my.package.structure#overridenMethod()
 */
 @Override
 public void overridenMethod(){}
```

They were generated by eclipse automatically but it seems like they cannot be removed automatically as well.

What regular-expression would remove all these occurences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treat the newlines as just more whitespace:

```
\s*/\*\s*\* \(non-Javadoc\)\s*\* @see \S+\s*\*/
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/Dt1XUwP43i)

Comment: This one that I created covers a few more cases including if there is a newline below the `(non-Javadoc)` line:
http://rubular.com/r/b1M82KZ52n

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(?s)/\*[^\*].+?\*/
```

`(?s)` at the beginning is a flag to enable multiline matching.

`[^\*]` is used to skip catching two consecutive `*` which correspond to Javadoc-style comments.

Comment: Thank you! I see where this is going. However, Bohemians solution is more precise as your solution would remove other cases as well